# Question about saving and loading objects in Android

Tags: android, gson

Lately I have been getting into Android development. I have done a lot of basic tutorials and made a couple small apps but one thing I do not understand is the practices of saving and loading objects. I understand the differences between external and internal storage, shared preferences, and databases; I just get confused when implementing them.

In one of my previous projects I used Gson to convert my custom object to json and save it to internal storage immediately after the object was created. Then, every time the user opened the application I would pull all the objects (they were all the same class) and put them into an array so my app could use them. This just does not seem right to me and I was wondering if someone could tell me if this is a good practice or explain to me why it is not and what the alternatives are.

I am currently working on a note taking app. I have a note object that has a title, body, and date created. I was thinking of doing the same thing as described above. When the user creates a note it will convert to json and save it internally. If the user ever closes the app and reopens it, it will load the json, convert them back to objects, and put them in an array so I can display them and allow the user to view and edit them.

Is this is a good practice? Is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have structured data like you should go for an SQLite db imo. You can use Android Room to map them to objects. Fetching the data like that will be much faster in larger volumes and you can filter for specific types etc. without performance hits.

Comment: @JensV Thanks for the reply. I think I will attempt to use an SQLite db. As for when to save and load, is it recommended to save upon creation and load everything when the app loads, as described above?

Comment: Follow @JensV 's advice. I've linked some resources in the answer to help you start.

Comment: @Dallas For small volumes it doesn't really matter. As soon as the data volume increases (which it very vell might for your case), you should load the data as you're displaying the UI, and only load what is needed. Save upon creation is the way to go. (Also note loading from the database cannot happen on the UI thread. You could look into ViewModels for a good way to handle this)

Answer (score 2):

You should save your data into the on-device SQLite database instead of JSON. Look into Room Persistence Library for a much smoother way of saving your objects in SQLite.

[Room Persistence Library Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)

[Google Android Developer Video on Youtube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKWh4ckvFPM)

You can follow the linked examples, sample and [Google Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-persistence/#0) to learn it quickly. It's fairly easy.

Or, you can go the not so recommended way of using SQLite directly - Read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite).

Answer (score 1):

That's unnecessary, why not simply use an SQLite database. Why do you want to save them as JSON?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just assumed that was the easiest way as I am not planning on having more than ~20 notes at a time. I will switch to using the database instead. As for when to save and load, does my described way sound correct? Save on creation, load and app load?